# Select numeric string with dots and colon

Tags: r, regex, string, substring, gsub

I have this string

```
string <- "Hospitalization from 25.1.2018 to 26.1.2018", "Date of hospitalization was from 28.8.2019 8:15", "Date of arrival 30.6.2018 20:30 to hospital")
```

And I would like to get on the numeric part of string (with dots and colons) to have this

```
print(dates)

    c("25.1.2018", "26.1.2018", "28.8.2019 8:15", "30.6.2018 20:30")
```

I have tried

```
dates <- gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", string)
```

But it gives me just first number before first dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(string, "\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{4}(?:\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})?"))
# => [1] "25.1.2018"       "26.1.2018"       "28.8.2019 8:15"  "30.6.2018 20:30"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZWpzKr/1).

**Details**

- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d{1,2}\.\d{4}` - one or two digits, a dot and four digits
- `(?:\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` - one or two digits, `:` and one or two digits.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sapply`:

```
sapply(str_extract_all(string, "[0-9.:]+"), paste0, collapse = " ")
[1] "25.1.2018 26.1.2018" "28.8.2019 8:15"      "30.6.2018 20:30"
```